# Is there any better way to compare these values in C#?

Tags: c#, compare

I have method for comparing values like this:

```
protected bool CompareValues(string a="", int b=0, string c="", int d=0, string e="", int f=0)
{
int counter = 0;

if(int.Parse(a) > b)
{
  counter++;
}
if(int.Parse(c) > d)
{
  counter++;
}

if(counter > 1)
{
 counter = 1;
}

 if(int.Parse(e) > f)
{
  counter++;
}

if(counter > 1)
{
  return true;
}
else
{
 return false;
}

}
```

It works fine for me, but I am can't stand without thinking about some improvement if possible. Any suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: why are you increasing `counter` only to set it back to one?

Comment: I think that is obvious. I am comparing values and based on result return true or false. This was requierement for my recent project

Comment: @Eonasdan. I am checking condition. If 1 of 2 is true and third check is true, then I evaluate true.

Comment: Damn, man. Variable names don't cost a thing.

Comment: no... this code is asinine.

Comment: I am not sure why you are not handling this all as one if else statement...`if (cond1 || cond2` ...blahblah)

Comment: First, why are you providing default values here? Second, why provide default values that will make the method throw an exception?

Comment: @mlorbetske. Because I am using this method in many places and I don't need all of them all the time. So I used optional parameters

Comment: @black123 I'd recommend reconsidering that as the method requires parameters be specified in pairs. Making the parameters required and providing two overloads that just pump valid, default values to the full method would probably be preferable.

Comment: I don't think you have used this code without passing the optional parameters, without only one of the string ones this code will raise an exception

Comment: @mlorbetske Thank you. Finally some constructive answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform n-many comparisons of the form

```
(int.Parse(a1) > b1 || int.Parse(a2) > b2 || ... || int.Parse(aK) > bK) && int.Parse(aN) > bN
```

You can make a method that just accepts a set of pairs of values to compare

```
protected bool CompareValues(params Tuple<string, int>[] comparisons)
{
    if(ReferenceEquals(comparisons, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("comparisons");
    }

    if(comparisons.Length < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("At least one pair to compare must be specified");
    }

    var atLeastOneComparisonSucceeded = comparisons.Length == 1;

    for(var i = 0; !atLeastOneComparisonSucceeded && i < comparisons.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        atLeastOneComparisonSucceeded = int.Parse(comparisons[i].Item1) > comparisons[i].Item2;
    }

    var lastIndex = comparisons.Length - 1;
    return atLeastOneComparisonSucceeded && int.Parse(comparisons[lastIndex].Item1) > comparisons[lastIndex].Item2;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = CompareValues(new Tuple<string, int>("5", 2), 
                           new Tuple<string, int>("3", 1), 
                           new Tuple<string, int>("1", 2));
```

If you only ever need 3 pairs of values (as in your original post), you could provide overloads for the method that provided appropriate default values, like this

```
    protected static bool CompareValues(string a, int b)
    {
        return CompareValues(a, b, "1", 0);
    }

    protected static bool CompareValues(string a, int b, string c, int d)
    {
        return CompareValues(a, b, c, d, "1", 0);
    }

    protected static bool CompareValues(string a, int b, string c, int d, string e, int f)
    {
        return ((int.Parse(a) > b || int.Parse(c) > d) && int.Parse(e) > f);
    }
```

Of course, the arguments passed down from the overloads must be chosen such that the semantics are appropriate.

Comment: This is the best answer I was looking for. I did not want to specify all parameters in the way I wrote in my question, because if number of parameter increase over time it will look ugly

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in the middle why you reset counter to 1, however this is what I understood

```
if((int.Parse(a) > b || int.Parse(c) > d) && int.Parse(e) > f)
{
   return true;
}
else
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thats correct. I am interested is there any other way that I can pass parameters in some other form?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by some other form. Do you mean other types such as object or var?

Comment: By other form, I mean in shorter way

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
return (int.Parse(a) > b || int.Parse(c) > d) && int.Parse(e) > f;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but is this what you are trying to do?

```
return ( ( int.Parse(a) > b || int.Parse(c) > d ) && int.Parse(e) > f);
```

Comment: Yes it is. I do not have problem with that, I am just interested is there any better way of passing parameters than in my example.

Comment: what do you mean by better?

Comment: I mean what will happen if I have to compare more than 6 values.

Comment: you can try `params` which lets you specify a method parameter that takes an argument where the number of arguments is variable. [Read more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db(v=vs.71).aspx)